# Como configurar autentitcação Hangfire em Produção

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, entity-framework, asp-net-core, hangfire

Estou utilizando o HangFire para gerenciar tarefas em segundo plano, funciona normalmente quando estou em localhost, porém no ambiente de produção eu não estou conseguindo configurar a autenticação necessária para abrir o dashboard

tentei da seguinte maneira, mas não tive bons resultados

```cs
Classe Startup

 //Politica de autenticação das controllers
            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            })
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
            .AddJsonOptions(opt => opt.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =
            Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```

```cs
Classe AuthorizationFilterHangfire que eu criei

 public class AuthorizationFilterHangfire : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
    {

        public bool Authorize([NotNull]DashboardContext context)
        {
            var httpContext = context.GetHttpContext();            

            return httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

        }

    }
}
```

Estou utilizando o identity para autenticação com os conceitos de claims.
Porém o Identity sempre está como false, alguém saberia como resolver isso?

Comment: Como está recebendo a informação do usuário logado? Cookie ou header? Pode compartilhar o método `Configure` da classe startup?

Comment: Já consegui, obrigado!

Comment: Ótimo. O que acha de responder a sua pergunta com a solução que você encontrou? Isso ajudará outras pessoas que possam ter o mesmo problema.

Comment: Foi bloqueado a url direto no servidor, com acesso somente via VPN ;)